# How to make the arbitrage if intrinsic value is greater than European call value

Tags: arbitrage, derivatives, call, european-options

It always says if the intrinsic value is greater than European call value, there will be a arbitrage opportunity，but how to construct the portfolio $(S_t - K)^+$ or how to make this arbitrage.

By the way, is it true for every derivatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to construct the portfolio (St−K)+ or how to make this arbitrage

If you have this scenario on your hands then you construct the portfolio by putting as much capital as you can into the trade.  It's an all reward and no risk scenario.  Max it out!  You "make" the arb by buying the call, shorting the equivalent amount the underlying at the current price and wait for expiry to realize the profit.  Beware of a pending dividend or other corporate events though!

> By the way, is it true for every derivatives?

No.  This will not be true for Volatility derivatives (VIX futures and options).

Comment: Why is this only true for volatility derivatives?

Comment: Edited.  I forgot the most important word "NOT" in that sentence.  Thanks @DStanley

Comment: OK, so why is it NOT true for VIX options?

Comment: @DStanley.  Because VIX is not tradeable.  You can only trade VIX Futures.  For example, right now as I look at my screen, March 21 VIX 11.5 Calls are trading at 1.15 x 1.20 with VIX at 11.67.  You cannot make this an arb because you cannot short VIX.

Comment: @Noob My last comment was wrong as I wrote it in haste.  Look at further out, out of the money puts, for example.  Aug puts at the 17 strike are trading at 2.9 x 3 with VIX at 11.9.  You can't buy VIX to make that an arb.  Yes, you can buy VIX Futures but it is no longer an arb opportunity.  There is risk involved.

Comment: why there is risk? @amdopt

Comment: @A.Oreo Using my example above, buying Aug 17 VIX Puts at 3.00 and hedging them by buying Aug VIX Futures (trading at 16.80) leaves you with 2.80 of risk.  If VIX settles at 12 your puts are worth 5 (+2.00) but you lose 4.80 on the future (-2.80 total).  To make money you would need VIX to settle above $19.80.  It is possible for this to happen and to be profitable but there is no arb opportunity.  Make sense?

Comment: @amdopt Yes, but I still can't understand why the stock can make arbitrage, but VIX future can't, do you mean there is no future trading at current VIX? If there is, there is no difference between short a stock and short a future?

Comment: @A.Oreo The VIX Cash Index (the stock as you put it) is not tradeable.  It cannot make an arb.  Correct, there is no future trading at the current VIX level.  They only converge at settlement.  I'm happy to explain further but I think this link may help you better understand.  http://www.cboe.com/strategies/price-relationship

Comment: @amdopt True, you can't short the spot index, but you can short (sell) VIX futures, which should be what the option price is based on.  If market expectation is for the index to go down then it's perfectly reasonable for options to be priced less than the "current" intrinsic value (spot - strike), but not less than the "future" intrinsic (future - strike). It's the nearest future that the option should be compared to, not the spot price.

Comment: @DStanley Agreed.  However, the confusion that I am trying to alert the OP to is that when you look at a VIX option chain it shows you VIX options that settle and pay out based on VIX cash settlement but have little to do with VIX cash until the actual settlement day.  If one were unaware, they may think the option (or even the whole chain) is priced incorrectly when it is not at all.

Answer (score 4):

The intrinsic value of a call is the price of the underlying minus the strike (`S0-K`), so if you find a european call whose value is *less* that that you would:

- Sell (or short) the underlying at `S0`
- Use the proceeds to buy the call at `C`

and wait.  At maturity, the price of the underlying is `Sm`, and you will make a profit in either case:

If `Sm < K`, the call is out of the money, buy you would buy Sm (to close out your short position)

profit = `S0 - Sm - C`, which is > 0 since

```
S0 - Sm - C > S0 - Sm - (S0 - K)     since C < S0 - K
            > -Sm + K
            > 0                      since Sm < K , K - Sm > 0
```

If `Sm >= K`, the call is in the money, and you exercise the call (which closes out your short position.

profit = `S0 - K - C`, which is > 0 since `C < S0 - K`.

> By the way, is it true for every derivatives?

This does not take borrowing costs (since you do not need to borrow money in this scenario) or dividends into account, but it will work on non-dividend paying equities, commodities, etc.

Comment: The last caveat is very important @A. Oreo. Nice answer D Stanley